# Links configured in the template administration panel don't work on the website

Tags: html, wordpress

The problem on a Wordpress site is that even though links are set properly in the WP admin area (see attachment 1) they do not work once the site has been published. When using inspect element it kind of shows the problem (see attachment 2).

Clicking and opening the links within the admin area is working just fine. Other links on the website work correctly. What is missing here? [image: WP admin]

[image: Inspect link elements]

Code in WP template:

```
<?php if ($section['link_to_doc']) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($section['link_to_doc'] as $link) : ?>
       <div>
          <a href="<?php echo $link['link_to_doc'] ?>" class="btn-txt">
           <?php echo $link['text_of_link'] ?>
          </a>
        </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Repeater fields:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: some mistake in the template like missing quotes, or smth like this

Comment: Seems like a mistake in template. Did you try and check with theme developer?

Comment: The theme developer obviously did a lousy job.... so I try to investigate this on my own...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ACF link object is not returning the right output in the href because of an error in how the links where coded.

Usually you'll want something like this:

```
$link = get_field('link');

<a href="<?= $link['url']) ?>"<?= $link['title'] ?></a>
```

That's providing the ACF field is not nested, and the field name is 'link' and there's just one.

Amended code (presumably):

```
<?php if ($section['link_to_doc']) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($section['link_to_doc'] as $link) : ?>
       <div>
          <a href="<?= $link['url'] ?>" class="btn-txt">
           <?= $link['text_of_link'] ?>
          </a>
        </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Even thought the whole concept is not the best, as you wouldn't create an extra custom field to put the text of the link since you can use $link['title'] for that but yeah...

Edit 2:

According to your screenshot edit the a to be:

```
      <a href="<?= $link['link'] ?>" class="btn-txt">
       <?= $link['text_of_link'] ?>
      </a>
```

Comment: I have added the specific code in my post from within the WP template responsible for the link problem.

Comment: Just added an amended snippet for that.

Comment: @Alex If that doesn't work, go to the ACF custom fields and try to screenshot that specific fields so that we can help you out.

Comment: Screenshot has been added to orig. post.

Comment: @Alex Thanks but, I'd need the fields of the repeater that the field in the screenshot has

Comment: Repeater fields added

Comment: Amended, that should be it.

Comment: I am still having troubles. But at least I know in which direction I need to look at. Anyway. Thank you very much for your time, help and input!!